# Unable to fetch URL from any source - while running BitBake

Tags: linux-kernel, embedded-linux, yocto, bitbake

I am facing an issue where yocto can't seem to find the file indicated in `SRC_URI` of the `bbappend` file located at:

```
sources/meta-connectivity/recipes-kernel/linux-libc-headers/linux-libc-headers_%.bbappend
```

Error message says:

```
linux-libc-headers-4.14-r0 do_fetch: Fetcher failure for URL: 'file://binder.h'. Unable to fetch URL from any source.
linux-libc-headers-4.14-r0 do_fetch: Function failed: base_do_fetch
```

And it looks for the file in the paths `sources/meta-fsl-bsp-release/imx/meta-bsp/recipes-kernel/linux-libc-headers/` and `<root-dir>/downloads`.

From my understanding, `FILESEXTRAPATHS` tells yocto the path where to look for the `file://`, which is defined in `sources/meta-connectivity/recipes-kernel/linux-kernel/linux-imx_%.bbappend` as

```
FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend := "${BSPDIR}/sources:${THISDIR}/files:"
```

**Question**

What does `THISDIR` really referring to here? According to [this documentation](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/1.4.2/ref-manual/ref-manual.html#var-THISDIR), it's the directory being parsed by the bitbake currently, which to me is still not clear. Is anyone able to see why yocto looks for the file inside `sources/meta-fsl-bsp-release/imx/meta-bsp/recipes-kernel/linux-libc-headers/`? Is this what `FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend` corresponds to?